# How to scrape amazon rating values in pyhton selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I trying to get the rating values from [amazon site](https://www.amazon.in/POWER-YOUR-SUBCONSCIOUS-MIND-ebook/dp/B083VZ2S4K/ref=pd_rhf_d_cr_s_pd_crcbs_sccl_1_1/259-8540866-0812544?pd_rd_w=GJm79&content-id=amzn1.sym.5d8cdd8d-be53-4391-b82d-376d461d85f0&pf_rd_p=5d8cdd8d-be53-4391-b82d-376d461d85f0&pf_rd_r=5VVNCWVMQQA3CXSMNGC5&pd_rd_wg=bh6vo&pd_rd_r=6bcb7989-bc35-4760-8608-a4da49b5148e&pd_rd_i=B083VZ2S4K&psc=1)

I applied every method but unable to get the rating values. one more thing to consider that this ratings don't have any hyperlinks.

[image]

```
for item in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-hook='review']"))):
    try:
        rating = item.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class*='a-link-normal']").get_attribute("title")
    except:
        rating= item.find_elements_by_xpath('/div[2]/i/span')
        for value in rating:
            rating= value.text
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.text`, you can use alternatively `.get_attribute()` to get the text content from a HTMl element. The following code worked for me:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    lst_of_ratings = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "review-rating")
    for value in lst_of_ratings:
        rating = value.get_attribute('textContent')
        print(rating)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Webelement.Attribute("textContent")` is the solution worked for me.

Though I am not doing it via python,  methods remain similar.